# Using threads in listView

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, listview, android-listview

I have an activity with a listView. The listView contains Spanned items.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Spanned xxx = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.xxx));
    Spanned yyy = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.yyy));
    Spanned zzz = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.zzz));
    ...

    Spanned abc[] = { xxx, yyy, zzz, ... };

    abc_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(this, R.layout.abc, R.id.abc, abc);
    abc_view.setAdapter(abc_adapter);
```

As I have 200 spanned items the application gets really slow. Is there a possiblity to use threading here to increase the performance? 
Like getting the formatting for the Spanned items in a thread?

Comment: what is slow? Initialization? Or scrolling = adapter?

Comment: then yes you can run it on thread, but mind that setAdapter should occur after array is initialized. so you have to show something to the user before it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to load all items first and only then show them, threading is not going to help (much) - it will still take as long to initialize. The only thing doing it on a separate thread will get you is responsiveness as you take the loading away from the UI thread.

To actually make this faster, you should consider implementing your own adapter, e.g. by extending `ArrayAdapter`. In the `getView()` method, you'll do the `Html.fromHtml(stringData[position]);` and set the content of the textview item to the resulting `Spannable`. This does require you to have all your strings in an array.
There are [many examples](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) out there.

The benefit of this is that you don't have to do all the `fromHtml` at initialization, but they are performed on the fly by the adapter.

Good luck!